# setMinHeight is not working correctly in android.widget.TextView

Tags: java, android, textview

I am new to Android development, and there is one thing I do not understand, probably this is a bug, but I really cannot believe that this one is present for such a long time. Please have a look here:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/widget/TextView.java?av=f

The code in setMinHeight(int minHeight) {
sets the **mMinimum** = minHeight; to minHeight. Why? Whouldn't this method instead set **mMinHeight** = minHeight?

Also have a look at

setMinWidth(int minpixels) {

```
    **mMinWidth** = minpixels;
```

which is correct in my eyes.

**Edit: I need to programatically set the mMinHeight member, but I find no method to do set, so how can this be done?**

Comment: Note for future readers like me: If you have a minHeight set in XML, it seems that trying to change it in code doesn't work (Android 4.x testing).  If you remove it from your XML, you can then set it in code, and even change it (set multiple times to different values).

Answer (score 1):

Min height is done in a slightly different manner because you can customise the view to be so many *lines* tall. With width, you can do it the normal way which is what you've pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you can also set `minLines` as a measure of how "high" the view can be, and it uses `mMinimum` as a field that can refer to either pixels or lines.

If you look at `getMinHeight`, it becomes clear:

```
public int getMinHeight() {
    return mMinMode == PIXELS ? mMinimum : -1;
}
```

> the minimum height of this TextView expressed in pixels, or -1 if the minimum height was set in number of lines instead using or .setLines(int).

So `mMinimum` **is** the correct field to use, it is dual-purpose.

Kudos to you for pre-emptively looking through the source-code though :)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but how can I then set the mMinHeight member at all? I have a table lyout with some hundred buttons, and I do not want to set the member for each button in the xml-Editor, but programmatically. Which method is correct for doing that?

Comment: Just use textView.setMinHeight(int heightInPixels) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMinHeight(int)

Comment: I mean yourButton.setMinHeight() of course. Button inherits from textview.